# What is the difference between these two IC suffixes: EUKG and IUKG?

Tags: integrated-circuit, markings

I am wondering what is the difference between these two ICs:

- LTC3886EUKG-1
- LTC3886IUKG-1

I looked at the datasheet and the following page, but I have no clues...
https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc3886.html#product-discussions

Where should I look for this kind of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "I" is guaranteed over the full -40C to +125C range, while the "E" variant is guaranteed only from 0C to 85C.

[image]

Comment: Whooh, I spent 15 minutes looking at the datasheet, you found that in two seconds!

Comment: We have lots of experience looking at all of the footnotes. :)

Comment: A tip I use is searching for the specific variant in the datasheet (e.g. LTC3886E). If the two variants are very similar, most of the time they will just refer to the root part name (LTC3886). The only time they call out a specific variant is usually when they are identifying unique characteristics.